# If $\theta_1,...,\theta_k \sim D_k(a_1,...,a_k)$ so $\theta_i,\theta_j \sim D_2(a_i,a_j)$?

Tags: probability, multivariate-analysis

I'd like to know if $\theta_1,...,\theta_k \sim D_k(a_1,...,a_k)$ implies to $\theta_i,\theta_j \sim D_2(a_i,a_j)$, with $i,j \in \{1,...,k\}$ and  $D_{(.)}$ is any multivariate distribution that is if $D_{(.)}$ can assume any number (finite) of dimensions and each r.v $\theta_l$ regards a parameter $a_l$ so the distribution of any pair as $\theta_i,\theta_j$ is the told distribution $D_{(.)}$, but bivariate, with the parameters $a_i$,$a_j$ setted on the k-variate distribution which regards the density of $\theta_1,...,\theta_k$. For example using the dirichlet distribution, if it holds so $\theta_1,...,\theta_k \sim DIRICHLET_{p=k}(a_1,...,a_k)$ would implie to $\theta_i,\theta_j \sim DIRICHLET_{p=2}(a_i,a_j)$ where $p$ is the dimension of the random variable regarding the such distribution.

Comment: It's not clear what's the question? You're asking if any such distribution exists?

Comment: If $\theta_1,...,\theta_k$ follows a k-variate distribution so any pair of these parameters $\theta_i,\theta_j$, where $k,j\in\{1,...,k\} $, follow this distribution but bivariate

Comment: What is the question you are trying to ask? Please write it in plain English. You are not asking any question.

Comment: Your notation/assumptions are not quite appropriate; all k-dimensional distributions are not necessarily indexed by a k-dimensional parameter. Disregarding this, the property you describe is called "closed under marginalization" and I am not aware of any general conditions which guarantee this property, but there are some examples (like the multivariate normal which you point out). 

I can just think of a few examples:

Comment: please see again, I dont why  my text seems weird I mean I would like to align its rows.

Comment: @bdeonovic My question regards each random variable to each parameter, but what you have told have been useful, if it get reopen so I'd like you answering this if you feel like.

Comment: @DaviAmérico what you wrote about the dirichlet is not correct.

Comment: Simple distributions which satisfy what you are asking for are random variables with a single parameter which are all independent. This is probably trivial so not what you are looking for.

Comment: My instinct thought says that this is probably the only scenario which is possible